# Make "exit" butten terminate the entire python script - Pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a script that is running the the background.

I want:

1. The "Exit" butten to terminate the entire script
2. The "Pause" butten to sleep the entire script for 5 minutes

I have tried to incorporate `os._exit()` but that seems to stop the script from running all together

```
def function():

    #Some function

while True:
    #Some function

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    if any(df['data'] > 10):

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        headings = df.columns.tolist()
        data = df.values.tolist()

        layout = [
            [sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],
            [sg.Button('Pause'), sg.Button('Exit')]
        ]

        window = sg.Window("Name", layout,)

        while True:
            event, values = window.read(timeout=5000)
            if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
                break

            window.close()
```

Comment: Have you experimented with `sys.exit()`, `exit()`, `quit()`, and `raise SystemExit`?

Comment: `from time import sleep; sleep(5 * 60)  #The "Pause" button to sleep the entire script for 5 minutes`

`import sys; sys.exit('Goodbye'); #The "Exit" button to terminate the entire script`

Comment: @Shail `quit()` did the job, thanks a lot!

Unfortunately, the script still stops when the GUI becomes active, which I don't understand

Comment: @journpy Great suggestion. Issue is that the part the first function utilizes sleep and this solution disrupts that process. Is it possible to separate into do 2 different sleep function?

Answer (score 1):

Using sub-thread to run your background script, and with only the method `window.write_event_value` to update the GUI when in sub-thread.

Example Code:

```py
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(window):
    value = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S%p on %B %d, %Y")
    window.write_event_value("Update", value)

def job(window):
    global running, disabled
    while running:
        if not disabled:
            func(window)
        else:
            window.write_event_value("Update", "Sleeping...")
        time.sleep(0.1)

layout = [
    [sg.Text(size=30, key='Time'),
     sg.Button("Pause 5s"),
     sg.Button("Exit")],
]
window = sg.Window("Time", layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True, finalize=True)

running,  disabled = True, False
window.perform_long_operation(lambda win=window:job(win), "Done")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT, "Exit"):
        running = False
    elif event == "Done":
        break
    elif event == "Update":
        window['Time'].update(values[event])
    elif event == "Pause 5s":
        disabled = not disabled
        if disabled:
            window.timer_start(5000, key=event, repeating=False)
        window["Pause 5s"].update(disabled=disabled)

window.close()
```

Comment: I like seeing the timer API call!  Thankfully it'll be released to PyPI soon. I've been using it to run state machines when there needs to be a sequence of operations with sleeps between.